# ActionScript: How to call an objects function within an array?

Tags: arrays, flash, object, actionscript

In Java it is possible to set the datatype of an array, and by setting the datatype to the object I am using, I can call the methods and variables of that object. For instance:

```
ArrayList<Object> name = new ArrayList<Object>();
name.add(new Object(variables));
name.get(0).method;
```

Is there any way I can do this in ActionScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Vector will let you easily call the functions of your objects which are stored in that vector.

```
var vector:Vector.<YourObject> = new Vector.<YourObject>();
vector[0].yourObjectFunction();
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html

Alternatively, you can cast the members of an Array to a specific type and then call the functions.

```
(array[0] as YourObject).yourObjectFunction();
```